# Protecting API visibility in Swagger and Oauth2 Token Storage in Browser Session/Local Storage

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger-2.0

I have created Spring Boot Swagger API using the below configuration. I have created OAUth2 and integrated within my Swagger Configurations. Everything works fine, I am able to see the Authorize button at the top right. All Apis are protected using Oauth2, the user will be able to get the details of the API only after successful authentication.

[image]

Now the two issues which I am facing is

1. After Successful Authentication through OAuth2 (Authorize button), I am able to hit all the services and gets all the response, but when I reload the page the access token which I got after successful authentication is going off.Is there any way to store the access token within the browser session/local storage
2. Right now all users even without authentication will be able to see all the Apis available in my project when they hit the swagger url. Is there any way in which I can hide those Rest Apis and shows it only after successful 
   authentication. An Example is given below

**Before Authentication**

[image]

**After Authentication**
[image]

My Spring Boot Swagger Configuration is given below

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

 @Bean
 public Docket userApi() {

  List < ResponseMessage > list = new java.util.ArrayList < > ();
  list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("500 message")
   .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());
  list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(401).message("Unauthorized")
   .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());
  list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(406).message("Not Acceptable")
   .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());


  return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
   .groupName("otrms-reports-api")
   .apiInfo(apiInfo())
   .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.otrms.reports"))
   .paths(PathSelectors.any())
   .build()
   .securitySchemes(newArrayList(oauth()))
   .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
   .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, list)
   .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST, list);
 }

 private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
  return new ApiInfoBuilder()
   .title("OTRMS")
   .description("OTRMS API for Reports")
   .termsOfServiceUrl("http://otrms.com")
   .contact(contact())
   .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
   .licenseUrl("http://otrms.com/service/LICENSE")
   .version("1.0")
   .build();
 }

 private Contact contact() {
  return new Contact("OTRMS", "http://otrms.com", "admin@otrms.com");
 }

 @Bean
 SecurityContext securityContext() {
  AuthorizationScope readScope = new AuthorizationScope("read:report", "read your report");
  AuthorizationScope[] scopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
  scopes[0] = readScope;
  SecurityReference securityReference = SecurityReference.builder()
   .reference("report_auth")
   .scopes(scopes)
   .build();

  return SecurityContext.builder()
   .securityReferences(newArrayList(securityReference))
   .forPaths(ant("/api/pet.*"))
   .build();
 }

 @Bean
 SecurityScheme oauth() {
  return new OAuthBuilder()
   .name("report_auth")
   .grantTypes(grantTypes())
   .scopes(scopes())
   .build();
 }

 @Bean
 SecurityScheme apiKey() {
  return new ApiKey("header");
 }

 List < AuthorizationScope > scopes() {
  List < AuthorizationScope > scopes = Lists. < AuthorizationScope > newArrayList();
  scopes.add(new AuthorizationScope("resource-access", "Get Resource Access"));
  return scopes;
 }

 List < GrantType > grantTypes() {
  GrantType grantType = new ImplicitGrantBuilder()
   .loginEndpoint(new LoginEndpoint("http://otrms.com/auth/oauth/authorize"))
   .build();
  return newArrayList(grantType);
 }

 @Bean
 public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
  return new SecurityConfiguration("swaggerClient", "", "reports", "reportstore", "123", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "", " ");
 }
}
```

Comment: In your first issue, you want to lower security, and in your second issue, you want to increase security?!! Maybe you should play the 5-whys game! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys)